# how to update database table values using update function in django

Tags: python, django

I have an entry already in my database table and i want to update it with the values `12` and `6`.  But for some reason the update function doesn't seem to be doing anything. I dont want to create a new instance, i just want to write over the value that are already in there. `PF` is the name of my DB table. I understand that the `objects` links both to the `pass_number` and `fail_number` attributes of the table model, so i presume that both would be updated with the values. However when I go into the table i still see the old values.

```
event1 = PF(
    pass_number = 12,
    fail_number = 6,
)
event1.objects.update(event1)
```

The error i see in the terminal is:

```
TypeError: update() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Do you know the primary key? Exactly *what* object do you want to update?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  yes they are pk 1 and 2 as at the moment they are the only 2 entries in the table. However these entries will grow in the future probably if i need to add more things to the table. I have updated the question to show the error that occurs in the terminal.

Comment: This is not actual code, cause managers don't work on instances. So no clue what objects is here. This could be a case of a model with a Manager that is not an instance but a class? I.e.: class PF(models.Model): objects = models.Manager # no ()

Comment: I am running from a file called ‘main.py’, that is held in my app called ‘charts app’. In order to process the ‘main.py’ file I enter my project manage shell: ‘python3 manage.py shell’ and then I do ‘from chartsapp import main’ and the ‘main.py’ file runs automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `PF` is your model name and you want to update a record in database.

First of all you have to fetch the record from database that needs to be updated. Then you can update that record.
To fetch single record you can use `get` method and then update relevant fields and save the single record. It will update your existing record.

Example Code to update single record in database

```
event1 = PF.objects.get(pk=1)
event1.pass_number = 12
event1.fail_number = 6
event1.save()
```

**NOTE:** Here please replace `1` with the primary key of your record that exists in database.

To update multiple records you have to fetch all the records that needs to be updated. You can use `filter` to filter the data or can use `all` if you want to fetch all the records.

Example Code to update all records in database

```
events = PF.objects.all()
events.update(pass_number = 12, fail_number = 6)
```

Example Code to update filtered record in database

You can see examples with filter and update on following link. Thanks
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update